# Revit API: Is SetLayerSelection the best solution?

Tags: c#, revit-api

Our company has hundreds of legacy AutoCAD details to choose from to import into Revit. We are using Revit 2021 and C# (Visual Studio 2019) to access the Revit API. We already have the code to create the drafting views and import the DWG files. What we still need to figure out is how to NOT import certain layers (i.e., Defpoints), and how to change the line graphics (color and/or line weight) on a per layer basis. Normally this is done via the VG Overrides dialog in Revit, but we would like to do it programmatically during the import process. Which of the following is best practice?

Solution #1:  Import only “visible” layers. This is our current, and less than ideal, solution and requires turning off layers manually before the import.

```
DWGImportOptions options = new DWGImportOptions
{
VisibleLayersOnly = true,
};
doc.Import(@detailfilename, options, detailview, out elemId);
```

Solution #2: Use the SetLayerSelection method under the DWGImportOptions class. This requires that an ICollection object be passed to the method that contains the layers to be imported. *How are the layers read from the DWG file into the ICollection object?* A snippet of code would be greatly appreciated.

Solution #3: Something else we have not thought of.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise. Snippets of code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Afaict, the method of choice to generate the lists of layers to import would be to implement an AutoCAD.NET application that reads the existing layers in every DWG file and processes them according to given rules.

Since that requires AutoCAD.NET work anyway, I would go whole hog and implement full preprocessing of the DWG files in that app, so that nothing more than you already have remains to be done in the Revit API.

My personal 2c only, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jeremy Tammick. I am curious if the code from your 4/12/2013 blog post could be used. I modified that code as follows, but the Open command throws an exception: "Method not available in MDI mode. Use Open method of Documents collection". Any thoughts? Many thanks.

```
[TransactionAttribute(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class OpenDWG : IExternalCommand
{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication app = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication();
        Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadDocument adoc = app.Documents.Application.ActiveDocument;

        string pfile = "C:\\Testfile.dwg";
        adoc.Open(pfile); //this command throws an exception

        //add more code here to turn off unwanted layers

        adoc.Save();

        app.Quit();

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```